# What package(s) are needed for compiling OpenCV with CUDA support on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to compile OpenCV 3.1.0 in Debian (Raspberry Pi) but would like both OpenGL and CUDA support.  I have been successful enabling and compiling OpenGL but not so successful with CUDA.  Right now the problem is I do not understand what packages are necessary to have installed before I compile.  I have followed (http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/11/compiling-opencv-with-cuda-support/) tutorial, but I have all these packages installed (except for the python virtual environments) but still it does not find the CUDA dependencies.  How can I check what packages are necessary?

---

My mistake, some responses and some further googling just confirmed why it's so hard->There is no support for CUDA on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: How can you possibly have CUDA support on a Raspberry Pi? It doesn't have any CUDA compatible hardware.

Comment: for cuda runtime support yoi'll need a cuda capable device = nvidia gpu. However to answer your question, afaik you just need the nvidia cuda sdk to compile openCV with cuda support..

Comment: @Micka: there is no CUDA toolkit or libraries which support the Raspberry PI. I doubt the CUDA installer would even install on that platform, let alone compile any code

Comment: @talonmies probably that's right ;) but the basic question was "What package(s) are needed for compiling OpenCV with CUDA support?" so while he will not be able to compile with CUDA on his raspberry pi, in general he can compile with CUDA support IF the cuda sdk is available.

Comment: @Micka: seriously, the basic question was "What package(s) are needed for compiling OpenCV with CUDA support ...  in Debian (Raspberry Pi)?". Read both the title and the first sentence, not just the title.

Comment: @talonmies my comment answers that question (indirectly)... and if anyone googles how to compile with cuda support he might find this question, even if he/she doesn't use a raspberry pi. You even added my comment's information in your answer (I added the comment because that informaton was missing in your comment), so what's the big thing about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV was built without CUDA Video decoding support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180762/opencv-was-built-without-cuda-video-decoding-support)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to build OpenCV with CUDA support on Raspberry Pi because that platform doesn't have CUDA compatible hardware, and there is no CUDA toolkit or toolchain available from NVIDIA which would install or run on a Raspberry Pi.

The instructions you linked to were for building CUDA enabled OpenCV on an Amazon EC2 instance where it is assumed that there is already a functional CUDA installation present.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, Raspian has always only ever been 32-bit and CUDA requires 64-bit.