# OpenCV was built without CUDA Video decoding support

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, raspberry-pi

After unzip opencv3.1.0, I was cmake with:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON –D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON –D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON  -D WITH_TBB=ON ..
```

But when I run opencv-3.1.0/sample/gpu/video_reader.cpp with compile :

```
sudo g++ $(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv) -o stream video_reader.cpp
```

I have received notice:

> OpenCV was built without CUDA Video decoding support

I'm using Raspberry 3. Thanks all !

Comment: raspberry pi has no cuda gpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 3 has no NVIDIA GPU, therefore CUDA is not supported.

From [NVIDIA page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html):

> CUDA® is a parallel computing platform and programming model invented by NVIDIA. It enables dramatic increases in computing performance by harnessing the power of the graphics processing unit (GPU). - See more at: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html#sthash.5wWaGnZI.dpuf

From [answer related to similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47):

> Q: Is it possible to use the GPU for calculations? (e.g. CUDA/OpenCL)
>
> A: Not at present - there is only a framebuffer interface for display purposes. There is no OpenCL and no plans for it nor is there documentation available to create OpenCL. **CUDA is Nvida only so isn't applicable.** Once an OpenGL driver becomes available you may be able to engineer some calculations via the GPU but how useful that will be remains to be seen.

**Instead you can use OpenGL ES or OpenVG to write code using GPU.** [Raspberry PI video api](http://www.elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs)

Comment: Can you tell me one solution to handle code on the GPU Raspberry

Comment: You can always use OpenGL ES or OpenVG to write code using GPU.  http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_VideoCore_APIs

Comment: Thanks you so much !